# How to bind a multipart/form-data file without filename to IFormFile in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In a simple controller action in ASP.NET Core 3.1 that accepts multipart/form-data parameters:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication
{
    public class Controller : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("length")]
        public IActionResult Post([FromForm] Input input)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return new BadRequestObjectResult(ModelState);
            
            return Ok(input.File.Length);
        }
        
        public class Input
        {
            [Required]
            public IFormFile File { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

When I send a multipart/form-data with a File *with no filename* (which is acceptable under [RFC 7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578)) it is not recognized as an `IFormFile`. For example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await Test(withFilename: true);
            await Test(withFilename: false);
        }

        static async Task Test(bool withFilename)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            
            var fileContent = new StreamContent(new FileStream("/Users/cucho/Desktop/36KB.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
            
            var message = new HttpRequestMessage(
                HttpMethod.Post,
                "http://localhost:5000/length"
            );
            
            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            if (withFilename)
            {
                content.Add(fileContent, "File", "36KB.pdf");
            }
            else
            {
                content.Add(fileContent, "File");
            }
            
            message.Content = content;
            
            var response1 = await client.SendAsync(message);

            var withString = withFilename ? "With" : "Without";
            
            Console.WriteLine($"{withString} filename: {(int)response1.StatusCode}");
        }
    }
}
```

results in:

```
With filename: 200
Without filename: 400
```

**How can I bind that File without filename to the IFormFile object?**

Edit:

I found in the [ContentDispositionHeaderValueIdentityExtensions](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Http/Headers/src/ContentDispositionHeaderValueIdentityExtensions.cs) the following method:

```
public static class ContentDispositionHeaderValueIdentityExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if the content disposition header is a file disposition
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="header">The header to check</param>
    /// <returns>True if the header is file disposition, false otherwise</returns>
    public static bool IsFileDisposition(this ContentDispositionHeaderValue header)
    {
        if (header == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(header));
        }

        return header.DispositionType.Equals("form-data")
            && (!StringSegment.IsNullOrEmpty(header.FileName) || !StringSegment.IsNullOrEmpty(header.FileNameStar));
    }
```

And a similar code in [FormFeature](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Http/Http/src/Features/FormFeature.cs), which I think is how it decides whether the part is a file or not.

Comment: Looks like the default modelbinder skips files without file names, if I've followed this to the correct source: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/FormFileModelBinder.cs#L142

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I'm having the exact same problem and it's a huge blocker for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterating what @Tieson T. mentioned in the comments, model binder requires files to have filenames regardless of their value.

I am sending a request using HttpClient, and this is working. If I omit filename, it won't work.

```
var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var streamContent = new StreamContent(request.Stream);
formContent.Add(streamContent, "Photo", "any filename is accepted");
```

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/FormFileModelBinder.cs#L142